# How do I know which are the first characters before "/"? asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string like that:

```
Dim temp As String = "Batch 634239100A/45 pcs booked out by vladut moraru on 10/15/2015"
```

Or

```
Dim temp As String = "Batch 322.3/4 pcs booked out by vladut moraru on 10/15/2015"
```

Or

```
Dim temp As String = "Batch 322/3/4 pcs booked out by vladut moraru on 10/15/2015"
```

I want to display `322/3/`

```
Batch is : 322/3/
PCS is : 4
```

I want to display just : `322/3/` of all string

I thought I'd find `322/3/4` and then to give it split after the last `/` and find value from before the `/`, but how?

Comment: Is it **always** in the format of `NNN/NNN/NN`?  Could the number of `N`s on either side of `/` change?  Would would happen if the string was actually "On 10/15/2015 vladut moraru booked out batch 235/689/45 pcs"?

Comment: In that string change just data and "235/689/45", 45 is always Integer but 235/689 is always Change. Batch "change" pcs booked out by vladut moraru on "Date Change"

Comment: 235/689/45 always change, i know 45 is always integer and display with /45. 235/689 is change with another string with "/" or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be use a [RegularExpression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), but there are limitations to this, especially as you're also including a date in the string.

If the numbers are ALWAYS in the format of `NNN/NNN/NN` **and** they will appear **before** any date then this will work...

```
Dim regExMatch As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match
regExMatch = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(myString, "(\d{3}/\d{3})/(\d{2})")
If regExMatch.Success Then
    Dim batch As String = regExMatch.Groups(1).Value
    Dim pcs As String = regExMatch.Groups(2).Value
End If
```

The regex `(\d{3}/\d{3})/(\d{2})` breaks down as...

- `(` Create a capture group
- `\d{3}` look for 3 numeric digits (0-9)
- `/` look for that character
- `\d{3}` look for 3 numeric digits (0-9)
- `)` Close and store the capture group
- `/` look for that character
- `(` Create a capture group
- `\d{2}` look for 2 numeric digits (0-9)
- `)` Close and store the capture group

(Note, in ASP.NET is it not required to escape the `/` character... in most other regex parsers it is necessary.)

---

If you don't need the `pcs` to be retrieved, then remove the 2nd capture group (so it looks like `(\d{3}/\d{3})/\d{2}`)... but then you would also need to remove the `regExMatch.Groups(2).Value` otherwise you'll get an exception.

---

If you need to check for a variable number of digits then use the format of `\d{3,5}` which would mean a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 5 numeric digits.

---

**UPDATE** - based on the new information provided by the OP.

Use this expression: `"batch (.+)/(\d+) pcs"`

```
regExMatch = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(myString, "batch (.+)/(\d+) pcs", 
               System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: For understand i put here another String, example: "Batch 634239100A/45 pcs booked out by vladut moraru on 10/15/2015" and i need 634239100A or antoher example "Batch 322.3/4 pcs booked out by vladut moraru on 10/15/2015". That i have trouble

Comment: I need just sequence before "/" representing the number of PCS

Comment: So, even though **every single example** you gave was in the format of `NNN/NNN/NN` you're now saying it can be different.  Thanks for wasting my time

Comment: Sorry, please help me

Comment: Sigh. Will it always have the word `Batch` before it?

Comment: Yes, and "pcs booked out by"

Comment: regExMatch.Success is false for string "Batch 322.3/4 pcs booked out by vladut moraru on 10/15/2015" and jump to End If.

Comment: Sorry, writing too fast for my own good... use this: `"batch (.+)/\d+ pcs"`

Comment: You have an extra `\ ` before the final `+`... remove that.  You also want to remove the line for `.Group(2)` as there is no 2nd capture group, so you'll get an exception

Comment: Finally - you're welcome :-)  Please remember, Stackoverflow works on [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), so please remember to mark my answer as accepted and if you feel it helped give it an upvote

Comment: But now doesn't work pcs, display Batch but for pcs = regExMatch.Groups(2).Value no display PCS :(

Comment: OK, this is my last help, as I'm sick of this. You said you **only** needed to display the batch. Now you say you also need to display the `pcs`. You will not make friends on this site if you continue to ask very vague and ambiguous questions.  Final change: `batch (.+)/(\d+) pcs` and now the `.Group(2)` should work due to the 2nd capture group

Comment: Thanks, is first post, next time i explicit all i need. Thanks a lot for you support. Have a nice day